# Cómo sobrecargar el operador índice e igual

Tags: c++

Como habrán notado el objeto string de C++ se puede modificar especificando la posición y el dato.

Por ejemplo:

```
String nombre = "eliel";
nombre[0] = 'E';
```

Quiero sobrecargar el operador índice (`[]`) e igual (`=`) para poder hacer algo como esto `Xvariable[0] = Xnumero;`. ¿Cómo sería?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias ser mas claro en lo que preguntas, dentro de la pregunta?

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @gbianchi, destacar también que el hecho de poner **casos de uso** ayuda bastante a entender con claridad tus intenciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las mejores maneras de aprender cómo implementar algo, es consultar una implementación existente. Dices que quieres imitar el comportamiento de `std::string`, así pues consultemos [su operador de indizado](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

Dispone de dos sobrecargas:

```
reference operator[]( size_type pos );
const_reference operator[]( size_type pos ) const;
```

En el caso de `std::string` el tipo `reference` es `char &` y `const_reference` es `const char &`. Por lo tanto deducimos que devuelven una referencia a uno de los caracteres que almacena, una posible (e incompleta) implementación podría ser:

```
struct mi_string
{
    mi_string(/* parámetros */) { /* constructor */ }
    char &operator[](unsigned indice) { return *(datos + índice); }
private:
    char *datos = nullptr;
};
```

El código anterior usará el operador de indizado para devolver una referencia a un valor interno, podrá ser usado como esperas:

```
mi_string ms("hola Mundo!");
ms[0] = 'H';
```